# Windows ping - 'ignores' ping replies

Tags: windows-7, ping, icmp

I'm using Window's built-in `ping` command to test connectivity with my Ethernet device ( a enc28j60 Ethernet controller and an  avr atmega), but Windows **ignores** replies.

Screenshots :-
https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5obg.jpg

according to the wireshark - everything is ok (reply packet has every value OK and time needed for response is computed)

Comment: The only thing you can reliable test with pings is whether or not pings are going back and forth.

Comment: device is connected directly to my laptop and ping tells me whether packet is received and processed by it. Delay after which reply packet arrives tells me how much time is needed for device to compute answer.

Comment: It's a firewall setting, most likely.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem!  Did you find a solution?